# jQuery .html does not work on a loaded template

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the following:

```
var appendCategoreis = function (categories) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/perouka/index.php/MainController/getCategories",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (item) {
                var temp = categories;
                $(temp).find(".category-title").text('dsadsa');
                console.log($(temp).find(".category-title").text());
                $(".categories").append(temp);

            });
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```

`categories` is an html template passed from another function and has the following structure:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h2 class="category-title">Categoria</h2>
</div>
```

When I am running the above code the console.log prints Categoria, I think that this means that the function above the console.log does not change the text, there are no errors on the console. Any explanation why this is happening?

Comment: what is `categories` in your script?

Comment: From the posted code, that doesn't seem possible, you're setting the text to `dsadsa` on one line and logging the same text on the next line, there's just no way it would log `Categoria` ?

Comment: @shaunakde As I wrote categories is the above html template

Comment: You need to pass the selector into `temp` and not the whole html template.

Comment: @shaunakde I think you didnt understand the problem. I am using find to take the selector and then .text, it works to get the text but not to set it.

Comment: @adeneo it should log dsadsa but it logs Categoria, I cannot understand why.

Comment: Seems like Rene gets it, the string is not an element, so you should have wrapped `var temp = $(categories)` instead to keep it constant. Did seem strange why it would log different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing an HTML string to `$()`, it parses it into a new DOM tree.

```
var a = '<div>';
// this creates a new <div> and sets its text content to 'hello'
$(a).text('hello');
// this creates a new <div> and sets its text content to 'bye'
$(a).text('bye');
```

similarly:

```
// creates a new DOM tree from `temp` and sets the .category-title text to 'dsadsa'
$(temp).find(".category-title").text('dsadsa');
// Creates a new DOM tree from `temp` and logs the .category-title text
console.log($(temp).find(".category-title").text());
// .append also creates a new DOM tree when passed a string
// so this creates a new DOM tree which is appended to .categories
$(".categories").append(temp);
```

Every time you call `$(temp)`, you get a new, different DOM node. If you change one, you don't change the others.
What you want to do is: Create the node only once, then use the same node for all your future operations. Something like:

```
// create a new DOM tree from `temp`
var node = $(temp);
// now use the same node every time
node.find(".category-title").text('dsadsa');
// logs the .category-title text inside `node`
console.log(node.find(".category-title").text());
// append our changed node
$(".categories").append(node);
```

Comment: Thank you, very good explanation. I just learn something new today. Great.